# increase website traffic by visiting website with python script and tor proxy

Tags: python-3.x, google-analytics, request, tor, alexa-rank

I want to make a script that open a url with python and stay in website for seconds and then do this over and over to increase website traffic.
with tor and request lib in python I write this script and I config tor to change IP every 5 seconds :

```
import requests
import time

url = 'https://google.com'
while True:
    proxy = {'http': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9150'}
    print(requests.get(url, proxies=proxy).text)
    time.sleep(5)
```

But when I checked my google analytic or my Alexa account, I notice the traffics which made by this script, aren't affect.
I wonder how can I make traffics for a website which affect and the tools like google analytic couldn't find that my traffics aren't fake either.

Comment: Well Alexa ranking doesn't stand anywhere and doesn't have any relevance with SEO rankings. Alexa just measures the popularity of  websites from users who have installed alexa toolbar. You can only show off your Alexa rank but, someone who knows SEO dosen't care about alexa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't help at all.  See [how Alexa traffic rankings are determined](https://support.alexa.com/hc/en-us/articles/200449744-How-are-Alexa-s-traffic-rankings-determined-).  Metrics are collected from a panel of users with certain browser extensions installed that report their browsing habits, or by Alexa Javascript code you install on your site.

Given those metrics for collection, visiting your site with Tor and Python code won't have any impact on your ranking.

Comment: I cant understand, even if I say in python code that open firfox and I install alexa extension on my browser, it doesn't work?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not.  There's no guarantee your browsing data will be used for sampling, and even if so, it would barely contribute to the site's ranking at all.

Comment: How about google analytics? Is this requests counted as site visit in google analytics?

Answer (score 0):

So instead of doing it with a python request, you can use selenium. Selenium with creating a browser and can execute mouse events with programming you can also use the time to put some difference between clicks so it won't look like a bot. Here you can check how to do it in details- https://ervidhayak.com/blog/detail/increase-traffic-on-website-with-python-selenium

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code and change with your parameters :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import random


def simulate_human_movement(driver):
# simulated mouse movement
    action = ActionChains(driver)

    # generate random point
    random_x = random.randint(200, 1200)  # random x point
    random_y = random.randint(200, 1200)  # random y point

    # randomize mouse movement
    action.move_by_offset(random_x, random_y).perform()

    # random delay
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 1.5))  # random delay between 0.5 to 1.5 sec

def open_links(links):
    # browser configuration
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    options.binary_location = "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"
    # create browser driver
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    # use full screen windows
    driver.maximize_window()

try:
    # used implicitly_wait for make delay on pages
    driver.implicitly_wait(90)  # 90 sec delayed

    while True:
        # open website links
        for link in links:
            driver.get(link)
            time.sleep(10)

            # semulated mouse movement
            simulate_human_movement(driver)

        # reset browser for first link
        driver.get(links[0])
        time.sleep(90)

except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred:", e)

finally:
    # close browser on end execution code
    driver.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # website links
    links = [
        "https://https://www.taktaco.ir/cisco-devices/",
        "https://www.taktaco.ir/sell-hp-servers/",

    ]

open_links(links)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is because you are sending a web request.
If I ran that code and removed the .text, it would give me a response 200 code.
You are just checking if the website is online via a proxy

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This does not appear to attempt to answer the question. How does this relate to the question regarding why the requests made by the OP's _working_ script does not influence their site's ranking in Google analytics?